# Jest test runner very slow

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

The project I am working with has over 2000 tests and 290 test suites. While I understand it won't run all the tests in a matter of second, I still feel that 7-10 minutes is a lot of time. Any individual test file with watch on takes 1 minute to run at times when writing a new test. Is there a way to speed up the jest runner. I have checked online and have tried various things like, running the test with "--runInBand" command, upgrade the version of enzyme, upgrade the version of node, specifying the test environment as "node". Some has helped it a bit, but its still so slow. The current version of jest I have is 23.6.0 and from what I have heard its even slower with the latest version.

Is there anything else I can try to speed up the test runner? Has anyone else experienced it being really slow?

Comment: Are you using snapshot testing? Have you considered using jest with the `findRelatedTests` option with only the staged files (real time-saver for pre-commit hooks)?

Comment: `--runInBand` runs all the tests in single thread so it will be significantly slower; without it all the files are run independently based on thread pool limitation(see https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6957); by default number of threads is equal to [all CPU cores](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli#maxworkers-num-string) count. so in conclusion: runner is already as fast as it can. you need to focus on your tests avoiding heavy operations there.

Comment: @Christiaan we have removed all the snapshot tests as we didn't see much value in testing snapshots, instead we test all the elements and its functionality which leads us to have a lot of tests.

Comment: Are you rendering the component for each test/it block? Maybe you could optimize a bit by reusing the enzyme wrapper. Have you tried detecting what is taking so long by adding some timestamp logs?

Comment: In practice, on some machines `--runInBand` can speed things up because there is less overhead. If you are developing and want to run a single test file in `--watch` mode. Just use `--runInBand`